# How to make an Chat box with wx.Python

Tags: python, wxpython, python-3.6

I am new coding guis, and I want to make a chat box where the user could chat with an IA that answer questions and FAQS

This is for a personal work where you have an IA that you can chat and interact with him, I searched tutorials on StackOverflow but are to have a chat online and it was more complex

```
app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'Chat', size= (450, 550))
frame.Show(True)
mati = wx.StaticBitmap(frame, -1, wx.Bitmap('chat01.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY), pos = wx.Point(0, 0), size = (450, 550))
wx.TextCtrl(mati, pos = (0, 455), size = (450, 50))
sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
```

I expect a functional chat where the user can write questions and talk to the IA

Comment: What is the question? Maybe see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: The question is on the title lol, how i can make a chat box where the user could chat with an IA

Comment: This is too broad. There are many things to do yet (correcting the order of function calls, using the created sizer, proper event handling, ...)

Comment: For example i want to make 2 boxes, 1 where the user could write a message and another box where that message gets printed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wxPython Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/)! There you will find some information about Widgets you need. To start with you should use wx.TextCtrl or wx.StaticText for inputs and prints in your GUI.

```
wx.TextCtrl(parent, id, value, pos, size, style)
```

and

```
Wx.StaticText(parent, id, label, position, size, style)
```

Also this code sample should give you a good starting point:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Example')
app.MainLoop()
```